# $S^T A S=D$ transformation. Do the columns of $S$ need to be normalized?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose I am given a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ and I am asked to find a matrix $S$ and $D$ such that:

$$S^TAS=D$$

I know that I need to determine the eigenvectors $v_1,v_2,v_3$ of $A$ and those  will form the columns of my matrix $S$. $D$ will be a diagonal matrix with the eigenvalues of $A$ in the diagonal entries. My question is this:

**Do the columns of $S$ have to be normalized?** I vaguely remember that they were sometimes normalized in lecture but I can't seem to figure out why. Am I confusing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, not every matrix $A\in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$ is diagonalisable. Indeed, there is a theorem stating that $A$ is diagonalisable if and only if the sum of the dimension of its eigenspaces is equal to $n$, that is there exists a basis of $\mathbb R^n$ consisting of eigenvectors of $A$ (the union of the basis of the eigenspaces).

Let $A\in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$ be diagonalisable, let $\{v_1,\,\ldots,\,v_n\}$ a basis of $\mathbb R^n$ consisting of eigenvectors of $A$, and let $\lambda_1,\,\ldots,\,\lambda_n$ the corresponding eigenvalues. The matrix $S\in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$ whose columns are $v_1,\,\ldots,\,v_n$ satisfies $S^{-1}AS=D$, where $D$ is the diagonal matrix with entries $\lambda_1,\,\ldots,\,\lambda_n$ on the diagonal. This construction does *not* require $S$ to have normalised columns.

The spectral theorem states that $A$ is symmetric if and only if there exists an orthonormal basis $\mathcal B$ of $\mathbb R^n$ consisting of eigenvectors of $A$. In particular $A$ is diagonalisable, that is $S^{-1}AS=D$, where $S$ and $D$ are as in the previous paragraph. Moreover $\mathcal B$ is an orthonormal basis if and only if $S$ is orthogonal, that is $S^{-1}=S^t$. Thus in this case the columns of $S$ are normalised since they are the vector of $\mathcal B$, that is an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb R^n$.